# Query in MYSQL to get the results for two values coming from another query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT l.name 
FROM locations as l 
WHERE
    l.location_id =',2,32,'
```

the ",2,32," values we get from another table. This query gives zero result, although there are values with location_id=2 and also for 32. Please help me how to use ",2,32," to get result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to return values for ID 2 and 32 you can use this query:

```
SELECT l.name FROM locations AS l WHERE l.location_id IN (2, 32);
```

`IN` operator allows you to specify `multiple-values` in the `WHERE` clause

You can also use `NOT IN` to eliminate certail ID's and you can also add more id's to it just by separating them with a comma..

Comment: result coming from the another query only in ,2,32, format. Then what to do?

Comment: @user1629986 I guess you are getting an empty result in the first place

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to change your where clause to `WHERE l.location_id LIKE '%2,32%'`.

It allows for more than just 2 and 32 to be in the location id.

Another suggestion is to use one row per location_id. This is called [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization%20normalization) and it is important to understand why to use it. Yes it duplicates some data, but it will make your query easier. You can then do `WHERE l.location_id IN (2,32)`.

**EDIT:**

I just re-read your question and it appears your locations table is already normalized. You'll just want to use the second WHERE clause I posted.

Answer (score 0):

If your location_id column is a `VARCHAR` column that contains comma-separated values, then your `WHERE` clause should be

```
WHERE 
    (l.location_id LIKE '2,32%' OR l.location_id LIKE '%,2,32%' OR l.location_id LIKE '%,2,32')
```

But if your location_id column is a `NUMERIC` column, then your intention to get rows whose location_id is either 2 or 32 should be addressed by

```
WHERE location_id IN (2, 32)
```

Comment: result coming from the another query only in ,2,32, format. Then what to do?

Comment: What is the data type of the location_id column?

Comment: The data type of location_id is integer

Comment: If location_id is integer, then you HAVE to use the IN clause and not the LIKE expression. Now, since the other query is returning you ',2,32,', you have to somehow convert that into a list of integers which requires T-SQL or you can join your query with the other query and use the IN clause which is the right way to go